# AWS::CloudFormation::Init are commands stored on ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, cloud-init

I'm using [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) and have a lengthy list of [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-commands).

In my commands I'm using many [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) to drop in variables. For example:

```
commands:
  '01':
    command: !Sub 'echo ${AWS::StackName} > ~/cfn-stack.txt'
```

Once my stack is deployed, and the EC2 instance is created, is there a place on the instance where I can view the raw commands that were run with the resolved variables dropped in?

Comment: I wonder if this is more of a OS question. Assuming that your AMI is linux couldn't you check the bash history across all users? This maybe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31723/can-i-search-bash-history-across-all-users-on-a-server

Comment: Try `/var/log/cfn-init.log`, or look in the User Data that is passed to the instance (`http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/`).